# Infinite loop and Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am new to C. I am familiar with Python, Java, C#. As such, I am having problems with pointers.

I am attempting to implement a linked list in C using structs. As of now the program creates the root member, then adds one more member to have a list of 2 linked members. It then calls the print method that should loop through each item and print them. Unfortunately, the program is stuck in an infinite loop and appears to be printing the member->data addresses instead of the data itself.

As I said earlier, I am familiar with a few OOP languages. This problem is frustrating because a simple linked list is something I should be able to hammer out in a few minutes. Any help? The code is below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Member{
    int data;
    struct Member *next;
};

struct Member *createMember(int i){
    struct Member *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(struct Member));
    new->data = i;
    return new;
}

void print(struct Member *root){
    struct Member *current = root;
    while(current->next != NULL){
        printf("%i, ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("%i", current->data);
}

main(){
    struct Member *root; 
    root = createMember(15);
    root->next = createMember(12);
    print(root);
}
```

Comment: did u run it under a debugger?

Comment: `createMember` never sets the `next` link of the created structure to NULL. Your print loop is chasing an indeterminate pointer off the deep-end. If you're going to test for NULL you had better make sure one is *there* eventually.

Comment: I ran the code in gcc and there's no infinite loop and it printed both linked list `data`. But your leaking memory.

Comment: see the answer from @WhozCraig below.  A couple of tips, though, on your code.  First, you should check that malloc actually worked.  After you malloc call, you should have 'if(!new) return NULL;'.  Then in your main method, you should be checking that 'root' and 'root->next' are not NULL.  Malloc is likely to work, but never guaranteed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function:

```
struct Member *createMember(int i)
{
    struct Member *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(struct Member));
    new->data = i;
    return new;
}
```

allocates space and assigns your data, but never initializes the `next` member. The result is that member containing *indeterminate* data, and therefore invoking *undefined behavior* to even evaluate, much less dereference, the former of which is done here:

```
void print(struct Member *root)
{
    struct Member *current = root;
    while(current->next != NULL){ // HERE
        printf("%i, ", current->data);
        current = current->next; // AND HERE
    }
    printf("%i", current->data);
}
```

To address the immediate problem change your allocation function to initialize *all* members:

```
struct Member *createMember(int i)
{
    struct Member *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(struct Member));
    new->data = i;
    new->next = NULL; // ADDED THIS
    return new;
}
```

**Output**

```
15, 12
```

Other issues remain (memory leaks, the behavior of `print()` being passed a NULL pointer, more pedantic error checking, etc), but that is the most pressing related to your question.

Best of luck.

Comment: So, that fixes the code. Thanks a ton.

But just as a follow up question, what was the code printing before I fixed it? If 'member->next' isn't 'NULL' until I assign it to be 'NULL', what was it before I assigned a value to it? Just a pointer address?

Comment: @mstagg: like WhozCraig said, the initial value of `member->next` is *indeterminate*; in practice, it contains whatever bit pattern that was last written to that section of memory.  It may or may not be a valid pointer value (usually not).  Note that the `calloc` function will initialize the allocated memory to all bits 0, which will result in `member->next` being initialized to `NULL`.